# Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: AndroidManifest.xml when I imported MPAndroidChart's jar file into my project

Tags: android, jar, android-manifest, mpandroidchart

I have a android application that needs a chart, and I got the MPAndroidChart in GitHub. But according to the documents, I just copy the jar file to the libs folder,and then I got the error. I have searched some solutions in the cite,such as change androidsdkversion ,project->clean your project, remove AndroidManifest.xml in your imported jar file.But,they all doesn't work.
what should I do to get rid of the error?

**Detailed information:**

> [2015-03-15 09:54:01 - BLEReceiveEarSignal] Error generating final
>   archive: Found duplicate file for APK: AndroidManifest.xml Origin 1:
>   C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\BLEReceiveEarSignal\bin\resources.ap_ Origin
>   2:
>   C:\Users\MyPC\workspace\BLEReceiveEarSignal\libs\mpandroidchartlibrary-2-0-8.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be that I **accidentally included the manifest** file when generating the .jar file.

I just recreated the .jar file excluding the manifest, download the new file (v2.0.8) and give it a try: [releases-section](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/releases)